ktor "hello world" ignore routing
I have this hello world made using Kotlin and Ktor
suspend fun main() {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "localhost") {
        println("1")
        install(CallLogging) {
            level = Level.ERROR
        }
        println("2")
        routing {
            println("2.1")
            get {
                println("2.1.1")
                call.respondText("Hello, World!")
            }
        }
        println("3")
    }
    println("done")
    server.start(wait = true)
    println("end")
}

It simply doesn't work, when I try to hit http://localhost:8080/ I get an "Empty reply from server" and no log is added, the output after trying to hit it multiple times is:
done
[main] INFO ktor.application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
1
2
2.1
3
[main] INFO ktor.application - Application started in 0.043 seconds.
[main] ERROR ktor.application - Application started: io.ktor.server.application.Application@516be40f
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] INFO ktor.application - Responding at http://localhost:8080

I also tried removing host allowing for 0.0.0.0 and still doesn't work.
What the issue can be?

I copied the code into a new project and cannot reproduce. Please show your build.gradle.

I'm not using gradle, I found the conflict is with io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.2.7.RELEASE importing a different version of netty api, :4.1.101.Final instead of 4.1.111.Final wanted by ktor. Removing it everything is working, otherwise there's something that is silently failing
